Number of sylow 3-subgroups of S5
$$
|S_5| = 5! = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5
$$
$$
n_3 \mid 40 \quad \text{and} \quad n_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}
$$
where n3 is the number of distinct Sylow 3-subgroups of S5
How do I choose n3 since the possibilities could be $1, 4,10, or 40$.

Use MathJax formatting, please.

This doesn't feel like a particularly elegant proof, but it works:
For each of the $\binom{5}{3}$ choices of three-element subsets $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we get a Sylow $3$-subgroup generated by $(i_1\ i_2\ i_3)$. So either $n_3=10$ or $n_3=40$. It remains to show that $n_3\neq 40$.
There is a relatively simple formula to compute the number of elements of a given cycle type in a finite symmetric group (see here under "cycle type"). We can compute that there are exactly $20$ $3$-cycles in $S_5$ (these have cycle type $(1,1,3)$, or $[1^2\cdot 3^1]$ using the notation in the Wikipedia article). If $n_3=40$, then since any two Sylow $3$-subgroups intersect in exactly one point (the identity), we would have at least $2\cdot 40=80$ distinct $3$-cycles in $S_5$. Since this is impossible, $n_3=10$.

My attempt is that:
Since every Sylow-3 subgroup in S5 has order 3,then every subgroup is formed by a 3-cycle element like(123),so there are 20 different 3-cycle elements,notice that a 3 order subgroup$\{1,a,a^2\}$ contains two different 3-cycle elements and different subgroups have different 3-cycle elements,so 20/2=10,S5 has 10 different Sylow-3 subgroups.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.
